# The projection onto the orbit space $X/G$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally compact, Hausdorff, path connected and locally path connected space. Assume a group $G$ acts freely and properly discontinuously on $X$, which means $\forall K^{compact},~~\{g\in G:g.K\cap K \not= \emptyset\}$ is finite and $g.x\not=x~~\forall g\not=1$.

I want to show the orbit space $X/G$ is locally compact, path connected and locally path connected.

For this, I considered a natural projection from $X$ onto $X/G$. It is obvious that the path connectednes is directly from the continuity. Hence I guess it is actually a covering map. But in my text book, the definition of covering space assumed the locally path connectedness, so I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Covering spaces may be defined without assuming local path connectedness. Indeed, the proof that the function $G \mapsto X/G$ is a covering map does not make use of local path connectedness of anything. Many (most?) theorems which apply the concept of covering spaces also need local path connectedness as part of their hypothesis. So a lazy author might decide to put that property into the definition rather than repeating it as a hypothesis of every theorem. Apologies to all the other lazy authors out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $x\in X$ consider a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ whose adherence is compact. it exists since $X$ is locally compact. Thus $H_x=\{g\in G:g(U)\cap U\neq \phi\}$ is finite. You can shrink $U$ such that   $H_x$ is empty since the action is free and $X$ is separated. To see this, consider  $g_1,...,g_n$  the elements of $H_x$, since $X$ is separated, consider neighborhoods $U_i$ of $g_i(x)$ such that   $U_i\cap U_j$ is empty, without restricting the generality, we can also suppose that $U_i\cap U$ is empty. Write $V=\cap_{i=1}^{i=n}{g_i}^{-1}(U_i)\cap U$. $V$ is open contains $x$ and $g(V)\cap V$ is empty for every $g\in G$. the restriction of the covering map $p:X\rightarrow X/G$ to $V$ is injective, thus $V$ and $p(V)$ are homeomorphic. Thus $p(V)$ is locally compact and locally path connected properties inherited from $V$.

Comment: '$X$ is separated' means it is Hausdorff?

Comment: yes, separated means that.

Comment: I think you meant $V$ and $p(V)$ are homeomorphic.